# How to add license comments in a twig file?

Tags: html, symfony, comments, twig

I'm adding my license text in all files (js, css, php, ...), but I'm having trouble when trying to add the text in the `.html.twig` files. I've tried the below code:

```
<!--
Itransformer.es is an online application to transform images
Copyright (C) 2013  Manolo Salsas

This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
it under the terms of the GNU Affero General Public License as
published by the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the
License, or (at your option) any later version.

This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
GNU Affero General Public License for more details.

You should have received a copy of the GNU Affero General Public License
along with this program.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.

Contact: manolez@gmail.com - http://msalsas.com
-->
{% extends 'MSDHomeBundle::base.html.twig' %}
{% block javascripts %}
...
```

And I'm getting this error:

```
A template that extends another one cannot have a body in MSDHomeBundle:Home:index.html.twig at line 2.
```

I've also tried to add it after `{% extends 'MSDHomeBundle::base.html.twig' %}`, but I'm getting the same error.

Any idea of how to solve it?

Comment: Have you tried `{# #}` comments?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Comments in twig look like: `{# <comment> #}`

You can add license / author information to twig files somewhat like this:

```
{#
    @author    Firstname Lastname
    @copyright 2013

    LICENSE:

    This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
    it under the terms of the GNU Affero General Public License as
    published by the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the
    License, or (at your option) any later version.

    ...  
#}

{% extends 'MSDHomeBundle::base.html.twig' %}
```

Answer (score 4):

When you extend from another template, you have to code everything inside of defined blocks.
So you should define a block for the license and implement it like you did with 'javascripts'

```
{% block license %}
<!-- license text goes here -->
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: License notice intended for a person who editing the file. So the above doesn't make any sense